# rails linkedin gem not able to fetch connections's email ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, linkedin-api, linkedin-gem

Im following all these instructions to fetch my connections of linkedin in my rails app

here [gist](https://gist.github.com/sreeharikmarar/6364970)
www.gist.github.com/sreeharikmarar/6364970

It gives the connections very well, but this does not give the email ids of the connection.

`profile = @linkedin_client.profile(:fields=>["connections"])`

How can i get the email ids of my connections.

Comment: I think you cant (hopefuly)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get connections:

```
# view connections for the currently authenticated user
client.connections
```

From **[this Source](https://github.com/hexgnu/linkedin/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#users-network)**

**Note:**

> You cannot "browse connections." That is, you can only get the
>   connections of the user who granted your application access. You
>   cannot get connections of that user's connections (2nd degree
>   connections).

Reference : **[LinkedIn Connections Api](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api)**

Comment: it gives the connections, but not their email ids

Comment: @PallavSharma : Updated my answer please check `Note` part. If it make you clear/help you somehow to understand then you can mark as accepted answer

Comment: i actually want to get my connection's emails ids (my 1st degree connections) only.

Comment: Like i have an account named pallavsharma on linkedin and i have 500 connections(contacts), now i want those 500 email ids, thats it.